# Discriminated union with an already defined class

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I have the School class (with 2 constructors):

```
type School(name, antiquity) = 
    member this.Name: string = name
    member this.Antiquity: int = antiquity

    new(name) = School(name, 0)
```

And the types of building:

```
type Building =
| House
| School of School
```

And I want know what type is a building with the function "knowType":

```
let knowType building =
    match building with
    | House -> "A house!"
    | School -> "A school" // Error
```

The error in "knowType" is in the second case: "The constructor is applied to 0 arguments, but expect 1".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be

```
let knowType building =
    match building with
    | House -> "A house!"
    | School _ -> "A school"
```

You need to give a variable for the `of School` part.  `_` just means it is ignored